# Hide UINavigationBar for few pages on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have this code in my `AppDelegate` for the `UINavigationBar`:

```
NSArray *viewsArray;

ToolsViewController *toolsnavigation = [[ToolsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToolsViewController" bundle:nil];
toolsnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting_image.png"];
[toolsnavigation setTitle:@"Tools"];
UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:toolsnavigation];

MyrideViewController *myridenavigation = [[MyrideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyrideViewController" bundle:nil];
myridenavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_nav_image_2.png"];
[myridenavigation setTitle:@"My Ride"];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myridenavigation];

NewsViewController *newsnavigation = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
newsnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_nav_image_3.png"];
[newsnavigation setTitle:@"News"];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsnavigation];

CoolViewController *coolnavigation = [[CoolViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoolViewController" bundle:nil];
coolnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_nav_image_4.png"];
[coolnavigation setTitle:@"Cool"];
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:coolnavigation];

AccidentViewController *accidentnavigation = [[AccidentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccidentViewController" bundle:nil];
accidentnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_nav_image_5.png"];
[accidentnavigation setTitle:@"Accident"];
UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accidentnavigation];

viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav0,nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4, nil];
UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabbarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);

[tabbarController setViewControllers:viewsArray];

self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
```

And with this the UINavigationBar appears on every page. I want it to appear after few pages, like once the user has logged inn, the navigation bar will appear. That does not happen with my current code. How can I fix this?

[image: This is the screenshort of the navigation bar which is coming on the login page too]

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode. Edited.

Comment: What ever it. Can u suggest me the way plz

Comment: you can use UINavigationController's `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method - see the class reference.

Comment: Show your login page before tabbar  loading and hide navigation bar on viewWillAppear...after sucessfull login push your tabbar as well as unhide navigation bar on viewWillDissapear inside login controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bar's hidden property of navigationbar wherever you want it to be hidden

`controllerObject.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`

**And in your case add**

```
nav0.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

after the line

```
UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:toolsnavigation];
```

Comment: don't get ur point buddy. I have added that code but it's not working

Comment: ToolsViewController *toolsnavigation = [[ToolsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToolsViewController" bundle:nil];
toolsnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting_image.png"];
[toolsnavigation setTitle:@"Tools"];
UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:toolsnavigation];
nav0.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 Is the above code not working?

Comment: Sounds weird. But it must work.If you don't need a navigation controller for the tool tab then you can update your view array line to `viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:toolsnavigation,nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4, nil];`

Answer (score 0):

In your **LoginView's** `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

And then in other view

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```